# Call to undefined function new\Illuminate\Support\HtmlString()

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel blade component for the PDF layout.
Using this `{{new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(vsprintf(text('Hello %s'),[$user->name])) }}`function inside my HTML code to render my html, getting from the database.

The error is `Call to undefined function new\Illuminate\Support\HtmlString()`

I just recently upgraded my PHP version from 7.4x to 8.0. After the upgrade I started having this error while before that It was working fine.

Any ideas where should I look and what could be the problem?

Comment: Is there a space between `new` and `\Illuminate\Support\HtmlString`?

Comment: A space was missing. Thanks for pointing that out!